# How to equally distribute points to a LineRenderer's width curve as I'm "drawing" the line?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using the line renderer to create a "drawing" app, and now I'm trying to enable pen pressure with the width curve on the LineRenderer. The problem is that the "time" values (horizontal axis) of the AnimationCurve are normalized from 0 to 1, so I can't just add a value to the end of it every time a position is added. Unless there's a function I'm unaware of, the only solution I can think of is finding a way to shift all hundreds of previous values by an exact percentage as I'm drawing the line, and do this as positions are being added. This seems excessive.

I'm at a loss on what to do here.

This is the basic line that adds the point every frame as I draw with the pen.

```
curve.AddKey(1.0f, penPressureValue);
```

The "1.0f" is the position on the curve (1 being the last), so this just adds a point at the end every frame, changing the entire line's width as I draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way of achieveing this that is not in some way uncanny and performance intense.

Of course you can calculate it (assuming the `LineRenderer` starts with position count = 0) like e.g.

```
public LineRenderer line;
private int positionCount;
private float totalLengthOld;

private void AddPoint(Vector3 position, float width)
{
    // increase the position count by one
    positionCount++;

    // set the count back to the line
    line.positionCount = positionCount;

    // add our new point
    line.SetPosition(positionCount - 1, position);

    // now get the current width curve
    var curve = line.widthCurve;

    // Is this the beginning of the line?
    if (positionCount == 1)
    {
        // First point => simply set the first keyframe 
        curve.MoveKey(0, new Keyframe(0f, width));
    }
    else
    {
        // otherwise get all positions
        var positions = new Vector3[positionCount];
        line.GetPositions(positions);

        // sum up the distances between positions to obtain the length of the line
        var totalLengthNew = 0f;
        for (var i = 1; i < positionCount; i++)
        {
            totalLengthNew += Vector3.Distance(positions[i - 1], positions[i]);
        }

        // calculate the time factor we have to apply to all already existing keyframes
        var factor = totalLengthOld / totalLengthNew;

        // then store for the next added point
        totalLengthOld = totalLengthNew;

        // now move all existing keys which are currently based on the totalLengthOld to according positions based on the totalLengthNew
        // we can skip the first one as it will stay at 0 always
        var keys = curve.keys;
        for (var i = 1; i < keys.Length; i++)
        {
            var key = keys[i];
            key.time *= factor;

            curve.MoveKey(i, key);
        }

        // add the new last keyframe
        curve.AddKey(1f, width);
    }

    // finally write the curve back to the line
    line.widthCurve = curve;
}
```

---

Just as a little demo

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer line;
    public Transform pen;
    [Range(0.01f, 0.5f)] public float width;
    public float drawThreshold = 0.1f;

    private int positionCount;
    private float totalLengthOld;
    private Vector3 lastPenPosition;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.useWorldSpace = true;
        line.positionCount = 0;

        lastPenPosition = pen.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // just for the demo simply ping-pong the width over time
        width = Mathf.Lerp(0.01f, 0.8f, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1f));

        var currentPenPosition = pen.position;
        
        if (Vector3.Distance(lastPenPosition, currentPenPosition) >= drawThreshold)
        {
            lastPenPosition = currentPenPosition;
            AddPoint(currentPenPosition, width);
        }
    }
    
    private void AddPoint(Vector3 position, float width)
    {
        positionCount++;

        line.positionCount = positionCount;
        line.SetPosition(positionCount - 1, position);

        var curve = line.widthCurve;

        if (positionCount == 1)
        {
            curve.MoveKey(0, new Keyframe(0f, width));
        }
        else
        {
            var positions = new Vector3[positionCount];
            line.GetPositions(positions);

            var totalLengthNew = 0f;
            for (var i = 1; i < positionCount; i++)
            {
                totalLengthNew += Vector3.Distance(positions[i - 1], positions[i]);
            }

            var factor = totalLengthOld / totalLengthNew;

            totalLengthOld = totalLengthNew;

            var keys = curve.keys;
            for (var i = 1; i < keys.Length; i++)
            {
                var key = keys[i];
                key.time *= factor;

                curve.MoveKey(i, key);
            }

            curve.AddKey(1f, width);
        }

        line.widthCurve = curve;
    }
}
```

[image]

---

Of course this will hit performance limits after a certain amount of points. But I think this is as far as you can go for now using the `LineRenderer`. Otherwise the `LineRenderer` is maybe just not the correct tool for drawing.

You could of course go tricky and after certain amount of points bake the existing line into a separate fixed mesh using [`LineRenderer.BakeMesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.BakeMesh.html) and start a new fresh line with only the very last point as a start point.

This wise only the still unbaked part of the line would be actually affected by the moving of the width curve keys.

Somewhat like e.g.

```
public int meshBakeThreshold = 50;

private void AddPoint(Vector3 position, float width)
{
    ......

    if (positionCount >= meshBakeThreshold)
    {
        CreateSnapShotAndStartOver(position, width);
    }
}

private void CreateSnapShotAndStartOver(Vector3 position, float width)
{
    // create a new GameObject that will receive the line snapsho mesh
    var snapshotObject = new GameObject("LineSnapshot", typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(MeshFilter));

    // set the material
    var renderer = snapshotObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer.material = line.material;

    // bake and set the mesh
    var meshFilter = snapshotObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    var mesh = new Mesh();
    line.BakeMesh(mesh, Camera.main, true);
    meshFilter.mesh = mesh;

    // start with a new line at the same current position
    positionCount = 0;
    AddPoint(position, width);
}
```

[image]

You'll have to play around a bit with the threshold, `50` is probably a bit low, just used it for the demo. You want to find a balance between performance cost of iterating all the keyframes and baking meshes ;)

Comment: Wow! I wake up to find the most in depth answer I've seen. I feel like I need to pay you or something haha. Thank you so much for all these explanations and examples. I haven't had time to try it yet, since I'm still in awe, but I will let you/people know on here how it worked out.

Comment: The only thing I've come accross that's confusing me is that "totalLengthOld" is not assigned a value anywhere before it is used. Is this an error or something I am not seeing?

Comment: Nevermind, it works! I'll be drawing short lines in my app, so the "baking" probably won't be necessary, but I might implement it to be safe in the future. For now, it's very smooth in performance.

Comment: @KeepCool the `totalLengthOld` is initially `0` when there is no points in the line at the beginning ;) later you always update it after the line has at least 2 points in `totalLengthOld = totalLengthNew;` ;)